# Use of random noise in Generative adversarial networks

Tags: generative-models, gan

I was reading [Image to Image Translation with Conditional Adversarial Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07004.pdf). On its third page, it states that

> Without z, the net could still learn a mapping from x
>   to y, but would produce deterministic outputs, and therefore fail to match any distribution other than a delta function.

Here z is the random noise given to the generator as input. x refers to the labels fed as input for Conditional Adversarial Networks.

Can somebody please explain the above paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with continuous data, you might want your generator (or autoencoder, note your GAN paper mentions using encoder-decoder architecture)  to be robust to small noise, since corrupted input is similar to original input (for example noisy images still look alike).

I think this idea was first proposed for autoencoders in [Extracting and Composing Robust Features with Denoising Autoencoders](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vincentp/Publications/denoising_autoencoders_tr1316.pdf). The gist of it is that in order to **regularize** your generative model you learn to reconstruct inputs from corrupted versions.

For a simpler version of this, recall that MSE linear regression can be interpreted as a Maximum Likelihood procedure for $\beta$ where $y = X\beta + \epsilon$, $\epsilon$ being normally distributed noise.